# In android, is it possible to use enumerated resource ids in code?

Tags: android, enums, resources

I would like to declare some values in resources like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="Shape">
    <attr name="type" format="enum">
       <enum name="rect" value="0"/>
       <enum name="circle" value="1"/>        
       <enum name="square" value="2"/>        
       </attr>
 </declare-styleable>
```

Use them like this in the layout:

```
<view       
  class="org.frame_lang.saveandloadhierarchydemo.view.SelectShapeScreenView$Shape" 
    android:id="@+id/rectangleBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    framelang:shapeType="rect"
/>
```

And then be able to reference the actual enum ids in code using the xml decl somehow.  You can reference the attribute by:

```
R.styleable.Shape_shapeType
```

But don't seem to be able to do something like this for the actual values:

```
R.styleable.Shape_shapeType.rect
R.styleable.Shape_shapeType.circle
R.styleable.Shape_shapeType.triangle
```

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you will have to read it as an integer and compare with the defined `value` for each.